# Change text field input style if contents are changed from default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a small script to an html form. All of the fields default to the string 'pass'. If a field is changed to anything other than 'pass' the text field should change it's border to red outline. If the value is edited then changed back to "pass", it should remove the border.

My example is almost working. If I change a value it turns the box red. But then if I tab to another field that has not changed it outlines THAT box in red too. It also does not change back if I set the value back to "pass". I am working on this for a Rails app, but my JS skills are pretty bad.

My form and JS.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").keyup(function(){
            if ($(this).value !== "pass") {
                $(this).css("border", "3px double red");
            }  else  {
                $(this).css("border", "0px");
            }
        })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field h4">
  <label for="inspection_results_soiled">Soiled:</label>
  <input id="inspection_results_soiled" type="text" name="inspection[results][soiled]" value="pass"><br>
</div>
<div class="field h4">
  <label for="inspection_results_contaminated">Contaminated:</label>
  <input id="inspection_results_contaminated" type="text" name="inspection[results][contaminated]" value="pass"><br>
</div>
```

As you can see it will change the border if you edit the default text. But then hit tab and it will outline the next box. Also it fails to change back when set back to "pass"

Comment: I think you meant either `$(this).val()` or `this.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `.val()` instead of `.value` . Try below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("input").keyup(function(){
                if ($(this).val() !== "pass") {
                    $(this).css("border", "3px double red");
                }  else  {
                    $(this).css("border", "0px");
                }
            })
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="field h4">
      <label for="inspection_results_soiled">Soiled:</label>
      <input id="inspection_results_soiled" type="text" name="inspection[results][soiled]" value="pass"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="field h4">
      <label for="inspection_results_contaminated">Contaminated:</label>
      <input id="inspection_results_contaminated" type="text" name="inspection[results][contaminated]" value="pass"><br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use $(this).val() as documented here
http://api.jquery.com/val/

instead of $(this).value which returns undefined resulting the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: That won't solve the problem though because OP changing it based on class, not ID.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues in your code. To fix, I did the following:

1- I used `.val()` instead of `.value`

2- I rearranged the code, basically same logic, but different order. And it worked. For me, cleaning the code makes it work and I can't really explain what I changed.

3- I put the logic in a separate function.

Here's a workign example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function borderchange($input) {
    console.log($input.val());
    let inputVal = $input.val();
    if (inputVal === "pass") {
      $input.css("border", "solid black 0px");

    } else {
      $input.css("border", "3px double red");
    }

  }
  $(".inputfield").keyup(function() {

    console.log($(this).val());
    borderchange($(this));

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>


<div class="field h4">
  <label for="inspection_results_soiled">Soiled:</label>
  <input class="inputfield" id="inspection_results_soiled" type="text" name="inspection[results][soiled]" value="pass"><br>
</div>
<div class="field h4">
  <label for="inspection_results_contaminated">Contaminated:</label>
  <input class="inputfield" id="inspection_results_contaminated" type="text" name="inspection[results][contaminated]" value="pass"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pattern` attribute set to `"pass"` and  `required` attribute to match empty string, `:invalid` and `:valid` pseudo classes at CSS to set `border` property

```css
:invalid {
  border: 3px double red;
}
:valid {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="field h4">
  <label for="inspection_results_soiled">Soiled:</label>
  <input id="inspection_results_soiled" type="text" name="inspection[results][soiled]" value="pass" pattern="pass" required><br>
</div>
<div class="field h4">
  <label for="inspection_results_contaminated">Contaminated:</label>
  <input id="inspection_results_contaminated" type="text" name="inspection[results][contaminated]" value="pass" pattern="pass" required><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I love that this solution is done completely with CSS. I would use this but it does not currently work with Safari and I have to be compatible with the big 4. Thank you though. Great answer. Hopefully Safari will catch up.